# Entity Framework 6 strange wrong behavior when i set two references of the same type on a retrieved entity

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

First of all, sorry for my English..

I have this behavior.

Models:

```
public class Container
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Reference Reference1 { get; set; }
    public Reference Reference2 { get; set; }
}
public class Reference
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }        
}
```

If i try this code:

```
        db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        var container = db.Containers.Find(1);
        container.Reference1 = null;
        container.Reference2 = db.References.Find(1);
```

I find that container.Reference1 = container.Reference2 = db.References.Find(1)

I figured out that the problem occurs exactly when i issue "db.References.Find(1)" before property assignment.

When i do "db.References.Find(1)", EF performs a set on every property of type Reference in container.

If i put a breakpoint on the Reference1 property setter, this is the call stack:
[CallStack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2tYR.png)

Please tell me if you have an idea to solve this problem.

## Update

If i change my models using explicit Foreign Key Properties, everything is fine

```
public class Container
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? Reference1Id { get; set; }
    public Reference Reference1 { get; set; }
    public int? Reference2Id { get; set; }
    public Reference Reference2 { get; set; }
}
```

But i don't want to have those properties on my model..

Comment: How to you define the model? Is it code first? Did you define the ForgeignKey column in the database?

Comment: In the Main project i used code first (eg. modelBuilder.Entity<Container>().HasOptional(x => x.Reference1).WithMany().WillCascadeOnDelete(false) ) In this test i used code first by convention without any additional specification. But the problem is still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Container>().HasOptional(x=>x.Reference1).Map(m => m.MapKey("Reference1Id"));
modelBuilder.Entity<Container>().HasOptional(x=>x.Reference2).Map(m => m.MapKey("Reference2Id"));
```

What you see is probably becauseEF go nuts if you dont specify the foreign key (or at least the column in the database) and go nuts. And you need a ForeignKey in your database whether you want it or not.

### Some referrences:

Synchronizing the changes between the FKs and Navigation properties (explains why something is `Set` on calling `Find`
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx

Configuring a Foreign Key Name That Does Not Follow the Code First Convention
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620

Comment: Yes it works even if it is also annoying to have to specify the MapKey when conventions should do it for you.. Even if i do a migration after the change, the migration is obviously empty..! Thank you!